# How to find the spellbook for a card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-arena

To make the question specific, I'd like to find the spellbook for [Cursebound Witch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cursebound%20Witch).

My usual go to places for cards are [scryfall](https://scryfall.com/card/ymid/24/cursebound-witch) and Gatherer.  Gatherer appears to not have Arena/Alchemy cards.  I'm assuming Scryfall doesn't have the spellbook, because it's not in [mtgjson](https://mtgjson.com/)?

TLDR: I can find the spellbook in various locations, but is there a "canonical" source that's tracking these properly?

Answer (score 7):

Scryfall at the time of this post, has added support for spellbooks.

You can search the card name with [spellbook:"Cursebound Witch"](https://scryfall.com/search?q=spellbook%3A%22Cursebound+Witch%22&unique=cards). Alternately, you can click the Spellbook button below the card image to be taken to that search. For example, here it is indicated on the page of [Cursebound Witch](https://scryfall.com/card/ymid/24/cursebound-witch):

[image: spellbook button below the card image, indicated with a red arrow]

Answer (score 4):

**You can find the list both in client and from an external source.**

In the client itself, you can right-click a card that has a spellbook, and then continue right-clicking to cycle through the cards.

Outside of the client, you can find a list of spellbooks for Alchemy: Innistrad on the MtG wiki, [here](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Alchemy:_Innistrad#List_of_cards_in_Spellbooks)